# Sending complex JSON objects to Asp.net MVC using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm defining an object like:

```
data = {
    first: { Id: 1, Name: "This is my first name." },
    second: { Id: 2, Name: "The second one." }
};
```

Then I'm trying to issue an Ajax request using:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/SomeURL"
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    success: function(){ ... },
    error: function(){ ... }
});
```

But my data gets converted into an array like structure that Asp.net MVC default model binder isn't able to grasp.

```
first[Id]=1&first[Name]=...
```

What should I set or do, so jQuery will correctly convert these into:

```
first.Id=1&first.Name=...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried flattening your data?

```
data = {
    "first.Id": 1,
    "first.Name": "This is my first name.",
    "second.Id": 2,
    "second.Name": "The second one."
};
```

Here's a little jQuery extension to flatten your data:

```
jQuery.flatten = function(data) {
    var flattenFunc = function(flattenedData, flattenFunc, name, value) {
        if (typeof(value) == 'object') {
            for (var item in value) {
                flattenFunc(flattenedData, flattenFunc, name ? name + '.' + item : item, value[item]);
            }
        }
        else {
            flattenedData[name] = value;
        }
    };

    var flattenedData = new Array();
    flattenFunc(flattenedData, flattenFunc, null, data);
    return flattenedData;
};
```

Simply replace `data` with `$.flatten(data)` in your Ajax request.

Comment: This is close to my end result. I've created a simple jQuery plugin that does the transformation in such a way that Asp.net MVC default model binder understands it. http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2010/12/sending-complex-json-objects-to-aspnet.html

Answer (score 2):

How about trying JSON ?

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rakkimk/archive/2009/01/30/asp-net-json-serialization-and-deserialization.aspx
- https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js
- http://www.json.org/

Comment: Blog post you've linked isn't really a solution for my problem. It's just about JSON de/serialization in C#. Asp.NET MVC wouldn't be able to data bind incoming JSON unless a custom data binder is added. but that would mean I'd have to change code on the client as well as on the server. Thanks for the links though.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a function to make your N levels json to a 1 level json like this:

```
$.simplifyJson = function(startingJson) {
  var fn = function(startingJson, parentKey) {
    var result = {};
    for(key in startingJson) {
      var newKey = parentKey;
      if(newKey != "")
        newKey += ".";
      newKey += key;
      if(typeof(startingJson[key]) == "object") {
        var result2 = fn(startingJson[key], newKey);
        for(key2 in result2) {
          result[key2] = result2[key2];
        }
      }
      else {
        result[newKey] = startingJson[key];
      }
    }
    return result;
  };

  return fn(startingJson, "");
}
```

So when you do this:

```
var startingJson = {
  a: "hola",
  b: {
    c: "chau",
    d: "chau2"
  }
};

var endingJson = $.simplifyJson(startingJson);
```

In `endingJson` you will get this

```
{
  a: "hola",
  b.c: "chau",
  b.d: "chau2"
}
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/bY9nD/2/

Comment: +1: I awarded your answer but accepted the other one because it's simpler and more versatile (doesn't need to start from an object).

Answer (score 0):

Javascript

```
       var access = {
            Id: 0,
            HotelId: dropdownlistAccess.value(),
            RoleId: dropdownlistRole.value(),
            User: {
                Email: email
            }
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: "Access/Add",
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify(access),
            success: function () {
                refreshDataSource();
            }
        });
```

Working for Controller Action

```
    public ActionResult Add(AccessViewModel newAccessViewModel)
    {
      // Your code here...
    }
```

The AccessViewModel & UserViewModel field

```
public partial class AccessViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Id is required")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="UserId is required")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="HotelId is required")]
    public int HotelId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="RoleId is required")]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    public UserViewModel User { get; set; } 
}

public partial class UserViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Id is required")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Email is required")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }    
}
```