# JSON object(s) not binding to Model

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

Some objects in JSON are not binding to Model.

### JS

```
var filterSet = {
    "Filters":[Object1],
    "FilterSets":[{
        "Filters":[Object2,Object3],
        "FilterSets":[{
            "Filters":[Object4,Object5],
            "FilterSets":[]
        }]
    }]
}
$.ajax({
    url: '/ControllerName/GetData',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        filterSet: filterSet
    }),
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
}).done(function (result) {
    ...
});
```

### Controller

```
public JsonResult GetData(FilterSet filterSet)
{
    ....

    return Json(data);
}
```

### Model

```
public class Filter
{
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
    ...

    public Filter()
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class FilterSet
{
    public List<Filter> Filters { get; set; }
    public List<FilterSet> FilterSets { get; set; }

    public FilterSet()
    {
        Filters = new List<Filter>();
        FilterSets = new List<FilterSet>();
    }
}
```

The **Filters** list with *Object4* and *Object5* is bound, but the **Filters** list with *Object1* and the **Filters** list with *Object2* and *Object3* are not. Or perhaps they are but are not getting populated with the correct values.

So all **Filters** siblings of non-empty **FilterSets** are just empty lists.

It doesn't seem to be the JS object causing this weird issue. I think it's something with the Model. What's missing from the Model? Or what's wrong in general?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending complex JSON objects to Asp.net MVC using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377438/sending-complex-json-objects-to-asp-net-mvc-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

Renaming the fields solved the issue. Perhaps, the pluralized field name was too close to the class name.

```
public class FilterSet
{
    public List<Filter> FilterList { get; set; }
    public List<FilterSet> FilterSetList { get; set; }

    public FilterSet()
    {
        FilterList = new List<Filter>();
        FilterSetList = new List<FilterSet>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Racking my brains as one bind wasn't working, gave me an idea and renaming one field fixed it....crazy. +1